# Erlang wxWidgets app - Closing the beam.smp file once app finished

Tags: macos, erlang, wxwidgets

got a weird question which I haven't been able to find an answer to online so I'm trying my luck here.
I have a normal erlang application using wxWidgets, once I try to shut down my application I get the event that the wxServer has indeed entered the event which is connected to the window closing, I get a message that it is in the process of exiting, and my window does indeed close, but as shown in the picture below, the beam.smp on my toolbar doesn't close at all, I have to manually force the closing of the beam.smp file which sends a SIGTERM to the erlang terminal which also shuts down my erlang VM (which I have to reboot it later).

long story short, what am I missing on my close window event so that everything shuts down nicely without it crashing my erlang VM? I was able to read that wxWidgets behaves differently on macOS but I haven't been able to find how to correctly close the application.

```
handle_event(#wx{event = #wxClose{}},State = #state{frame = Frame,panel = Panel}) ->
  io:format("Exiting~n"),
  wxFrame:close(Frame),
  wxFrame:destroy(Frame),
  wx:destroy(),
  {stop,normal,State};
```

[image: The toolbar of my mac once the app is running]

Comment: FWIW, this happens to all OTP WxWidget apps as well. For instance, try running `observer:start().` in your shell and then close the observer. You can only get rid of "Erlang" (the OS app) by terminating your node.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the emulator from code with [init:stop/0,1](https://erlang.org/doc/man/init.html#stop-0)

Also, if your application is started as `permanent`, it should suffice with terminating that application. Check the behaviour in [erlang:application](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#start-1)